# Como preencher uma coluna de código para consulta com valores repetidos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server, view

Possuo uma consulta onde tenho retorno vários dados de cada usuário. Porém ao realizar uma busca, eu tenho como retorno os dados repetidos.

Sei que essa repetição dos dados se dar por eu não conter um dado único (que não se repete) nesta nesta consulta, como uma `primary key`, pois a base para esta consulta é uma `View` criada em meu  `DataBase`.

Sei disso, pois se eu adicionar essa linha em minha consulta (onde eu crio um campo `Codigo` com uma contagem única para cada linha) eu consigo retornar os dados sem repetir.

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Nome desc ) AS 'Codigo'
```

**Problema:** Ao adicionar a linha em minha View (SQL) a consulta não repete os dados, porém uma consulta que levo 4 segundos para realizar, ao adicionar esta linha a mesma consulta demora 8 minutos.

Existe uma maneira de retornar esses dados sem repetir pelo código, ou outra forma de tratar a minha View (SQL)?

O meu controller que faz essa consulta está assim:

```
public ActionResult Dependente()
{
   var dependente =
        dependenteRepository.Dependentes.Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matricula && r.SqContrato == contrato).ToList();
    return View(dependente);
}
```

O meu model está dessa forma:

```
public class Dependente
    {
        public double NRCPF { get; set; }
        public string NmPessoa { get; set; }
        public string Nome_dependente { get; set; }
        public string DsGrauDependencia { get; set; }
        public int CdMatricula { get; set; }
        public Int16 SqContrato { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? Nascimento { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: "Possuo uma View em meu sql". Essa afirmação não faz o menor sentido. SQLs não retornam Views, mas se eu entendi bem o que você quer fazer é enumerar as linhas. Não sei qual o objetivo disso, mas irei responder.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez nesta frase a ideia era dizer que retorno os dados de uma View( create View nmView as select...) eu adicionei a palavra "SQL" apenas para distinguir da View do MVC. Desculpe se ficou confuso, mas posso editar para melhor compreensão.

Comment: Sim, seria bom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa numerar as linhas pelo SQL. Pode fazer isso pelo próprio *Controller*, convertendo cada objeto dependente em um objeto anônimo:

```
public ActionResult Dependente()
{
    var i = 1;
    var dependentes =
        dependenteRepository.Dependentes
            .Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matricula && r.SqContrato == contrato)
            .Select(d => new { 
                Codigo = 0,
                NRCPF = d.NRCPF,
                NmPessoa = d.NmPessoa,
                Nome_dependente = d.Nome_dependente,
                DsGrauDependencia = d.DsGrauDependencia,
                CdMatricula = d.CdMatricula,
                SqContrato = d.SqContrato,
                Nascimento = d.Nascimento
             })
            .ToList();

    foreach (var dependente in dependentes) 
    {
        dependente.Codigo = i++;
    }

    return View(dependentes);
}
```

A *View* precisa ou tratar como `dynamic` o objeto anônimo ou receber uma lista de *ViewModels*. Por exemplo:

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

Ou então:

```
@model IEnumerable<DependenteViewModel>
```

Aí precisa definir o *ViewModel*:

```
public class DependenteViewModel
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public double NRCPF { get; set; }
    public string NmPessoa { get; set; }
    public string Nome_dependente { get; set; }
    public string DsGrauDependencia { get; set; }
    public int CdMatricula { get; set; }
    public Int16 SqContrato { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Nascimento { get; set; }
}
```

Por fim, o *Controller* fica assim:

```
public ActionResult Dependente()
{
    var i = 1;
    var dependentes =
        dependenteRepository.Dependentes
            .Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matricula && r.SqContrato == contrato)
            .Select(d => new DependenteViewModel { 
                Codigo = 0,
                NRCPF = d.NRCPF,
                NmPessoa = d.NmPessoa,
                Nome_dependente = d.Nome_dependente,
                DsGrauDependencia = d.DsGrauDependencia,
                CdMatricula = d.CdMatricula,
                SqContrato = d.SqContrato,
                Nascimento = d.Nascimento
             })
            .ToList();

    foreach (var dependente in dependentes) 
    {
        dependente.Codigo = i++;
    }

    return View(dependentes);
}
```

Comment: Nessa parde **Codigo = i++** eu recebo o seguinte erro: **an expression tree cannot contain an assignment operator**

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou certinho. Exceto que quando coloco com o **For()** eu recebo erro de sintaxe, mas alterando para **Foreach()** funciona perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Tava programando em Python ontem antes de dormir, aí bugo o célebro e tal. Já arrumei. Obrigado!

Comment: Normal isso. rsrs